# Clear all entered and selected data after click on button

Tags: asp.net, forms, syntax

I have asp.net page and it's contain Text boxes ,Drop down lists ,check boxes and grids

the question is :
When i click on save Button , how can I clear All data that entered and selected in this page ?

Answer (score 0):

Your can do this, with a little bit of javascript. Using a framework such as jquery, it makes it very easy to find all type of input and clear there value. Example given below.

HTML:

```
 First name: <input type="text" id="firstname" /><br />
    Last name: <input type="text" id="lastname" /><br />
    <button>Submit</button>​
```

JavaScript:

```
 $("button").click(function () {
          $("input").val('');
        });​
```

[More Info](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Answer (score 0):

```
TextBox1.Text = String.Empty;
DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = -1;
...
```

If you want to get fancy you can iterate through all of the controls and containers on the page and set their values to some default.

Of course, a quick way would be to simply issue a `response.Redirect` back to the same page.  This is essentially telling the browser to start over.  Presumably all of the values are blank to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use the built-in Controls.Clear() method on your form:

```
form1.Controls.Clear()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
public static void ClearControls(Control Parent)
{
   if (Parent is TextBox)
      { 
          (Parent as TextBox).Text = string.Empty; 
      }
    else if (Parent is DropDownList)
      {
          (Parent as DropDownList).SelectedIndex = 0;
      }
    else
      {
          foreach (Control c in Parent.Controls)
          ClearControls(c);
      }
}
```

and call following code where you want

```
ClearControls(Page);
```